# tf.Concat() does not result in concatenated tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

When using tf.concat(), I am unable to combine the tensors along an axis. What am I missing?

Outputs:

```
Tensor("concat:0", shape=(3, 4, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
(<tf.Tensor 'l_image:0' shape=(4, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'l_augim:0' shape=(4, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'u_image:0' shape=(4, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>,)
```

Desired Output

```
Tensor("concat:0", shape=(12, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Code:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((l_image, l_augim, u_image)).batch(4)

for x, (l_image, l_augim, u_image) in enumerate(dataset):
    concat_tensor = tf.concat([l_image, l_augim, u_image], axis = 0)
    print(concat_tensor)
    print(l_image)
    print(l_augim)
    print(u_image)
    break
```

*Note: l_image, l_augim, and u_image are images of these dimensions (32, 32, 3)*

Comment: can you add reproducible example? concating 3 tensors of your sizes (constructed with `tf.random.uniform`) with `tf.concat([l_image, l_augim, u_image], axis=0)` results in your desired output shape in my code

Comment: @DominikFicek I updated the code that i am using to test, please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you for your help! I do not know why it is not working.

Comment: looks good to me, can you confirm that right before calling `tf.concat` the shapes of the input tensors are exactly as you present them to be? I'm still not able to reproduce your problem

Comment: I figured out the issue: I was using tf.cast() which made my tensors - tensor objects not normal tensors. Thats why they have the <tf.tensor> and not the normal Tensor. Thank you for your help!!